# Importing Python.h into C++ Qt in (windows) doesn't work

Tags: python, c++, qt-creator, cpython

I need to call a python function in c++ and share data with it. I added python.h but I have got "undefined reference to _imp__Py_Initialize" and other used python packages error as well.
When I use MinGW64bit I do not receive any error but it stops unexpectedly.
I installed python separate from anaconda one.
Python version: 3.9
Qt version: 4.14
Windows10, 64bit

**Pro**

```
QT       += core gui

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets
CONFIG += c++11
CONFIG += no_keywords
CONFIG += file_copies

COPIES += python
python.files = someFunction.py
python.path = $$OUT_PWD


INCLUDEPATH = "C:\Users\A\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\include"
LIBS += -L"C:\Users\A\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\libs" -l"python39"

SOURCES += \
    main.cpp \
    mainwindow.cpp

HEADERS += \
    mainwindow.h

# Default rules for deployment.
qnx: target.path = /tmp/$${TARGET}/bin
else: unix:!android: target.path = /opt/$${TARGET}/bin
!isEmpty(target.path): INSTALLS += target

DISTFILES += \
    someFunction.py
```

** main.cpp**:

```
#pragma push_macro("slots")
#undef slots
#include <Python.h>
#pragma pop_macro("slots")
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QApplication>


#include <QDebug>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    Py_Initialize();

    QString sys_path_append_command = QString(R"(sys.path.append("%1"))").arg(QCoreApplication::applicationDirPath());

    PyRun_SimpleString("import sys");
    PyRun_SimpleString(sys_path_append_command.toStdString().c_str());

    PyObject* myModuleString = PyUnicode_FromString((char*)"someFunction");
    PyObject* myModule = PyImport_Import(myModuleString);
    PyObject* myFunction = PyObject_GetAttrString(myModule,(char*)"someFunction");

    PyObject* args = Py_BuildValue("(f)", 2.0);
    PyObject *myResult = PyObject_CallObject(myFunction, args);

    qDebug() << "Hello World" << PyFloat_AsDouble(myResult);

    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;
    w.show();
    return a.exec();
}
```

**someFunction.py**:

```
def someFunction(a):
    return a
```

Anyone can help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

So I solved it myself! After compiling, I added the python3.dll, python39.dll to my compilation folder and it works!